# Background wont display on view controller. Stupid issue?

Tags: ios, background, storyboard

I have a view controller, the background for which I want to chance depending on the size of the iPhone viewing it.

I have tried the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//Chainging the background for the different screen sizes. 


if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

if(result.height == 960) {


    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background Iphone 4.png"];
    self.view.layer.contents = (id) image.CGImage;

}

if (result.height == 1136) {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background Iphone 5.png"];
    self.view.layer.contents = (id) image.CGImage;


}
}
```

I dont get any errors, but at the same time neither image is displayed on any device! Can anyone help me? Surely this should be a simple problem?

I have tried to read into the problem but I am getting no where. I am using storyboards and I do have autolayout turned on. Could this be the issue?

Thanks for taking the time to take a look!

Comment: The problem is your screen sizes? iPhone4 = 480, iPhone5 = 568.0. What  you are checking is retina display.

Comment: Thanks Danypata! 

I can't believe I'd made that mistake. Thanks so much for the help!

Feel free to put it into an answer so I can rep you...

Comment: No problem, you should mark @Wain answer as the accepted one because he posted the answer just after I posted the comment and his answer is the right one.(Has explanations to) :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a bit of research on float number equivalence. The changes of the height being exactly equal to 960 or 1136 is slim (though they could be). You should check for `>=` or `<=` instead.

The chances of matching 960 pr 1136 is especially slim as they are the @2x sizes. The true size of the frame will be 480 or 568.

So, try something like `if (height > 481)` and a simple `else`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

So from now on you can use it in standard if/else statements:

```
if( IS_IPHONE_5 )
 {}
else
{}
```